# VueUse useEventListener - document not defined in Nuxt3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, addeventlistener, nuxtjs3, vueuse

I though that `useEventListener()` from VueUse was supposed to automatically put the event listener registration into the `onMounted` hook, however, when I tried to use it in the following way, I got a Nuxt3 error - `document is not defined`:

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
useEventListener(document, 'keydown', (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
    if (e.key === 'Escape') {
        // ...
    }
})
</script>
```

Even on their website, they don't put the composable into a lifecycle hook: https://vueuse.org/core/useEventListener/

Did I misunderstand something? When I wrap it with `if (process.client) {` it obviously works, however, that defeats the purpose of having a composable that is supposed to make it easier to work with event listeners in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does work as intended. Should be a problem with your Nuxt setup.

[SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#__DEV__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)

```js
const { createApp } = Vue
const { useEventListener } = VueUse

const App = { 
  setup() {   
    console.log(`${new Date().toLocaleTimeString()} Start`)
    const cleanup = useEventListener(document, 'keydown', (e) => {
      if (e.key === 'Escape') {
         alert(`${new Date().toLocaleTimeString()} Esc`)
      }
   })
   return { cleanup }
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
const vm = app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 2; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
<button @click="cleanup">cleanup</button>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@vueuse/shared"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@vueuse/core"></script>
```

Comment: Hmm, thanks, I will test whether it happens in a bare Nuxt project too...

Comment: Looks like it might have been a bug. Now, after updating the dependencies, it works as intended.